# Why can't my page controller scroll infinitely backwards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, infinite-scroll

I have created a page controller that has three view controllers that can scroll infinitely forward (eg: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1 -> etc) however when I am on the first view controller and try to scroll backwards it goes to a white screen and doesn't scroll backwards properly ?

I can scroll backwards fine until I reach the first view controller but after that its just the white screen
(eg: 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> white screen)

I want to be able to scroll backwards infinitely so it looks like this
(eg: 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 3 -> etc)

Here is my code for my page view controller, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong?

Can someone please help me make my page view controller scroll infinitely backwards? Thanks!

```
    #import "PageViewController.h"

@interface PageViewController ()

@end

@implementation PageViewController
{
    NSArray *myViewControllers;


}




- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.delegate = self;
    self.dataSource = self;

    UIViewController *p1 = [self.storyboard
                            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContentViewController1"];
    UIViewController *p2 = [self.storyboard
                            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContentViewController2"];
    UIViewController *p3 = [self.storyboard
                            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContentViewController3"];

    myViewControllers = @[p1,p2,p3];

    [self setViewControllers:@[p1]
                   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                    animated:NO completion:nil];




    NSLog(@"loaded!");

}




-(UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    return myViewControllers[index];
}



-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
     viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [myViewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

    --currentIndex;
    currentIndex = currentIndex % (myViewControllers.count);
    return [myViewControllers objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
}



-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
      viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [myViewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

    ++currentIndex;
    currentIndex = currentIndex % (myViewControllers.count);
    return [myViewControllers objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
}


-(NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:
(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return myViewControllers.count;
}

-(NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:
(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `viewControllerBeforeViewController` function, the modulo operator % doesn't do what you want. Your numbers go like this, and % doesn't loop you back to your third view:

2, 1, 0, -1.

When going backward, you have to check if you've wrapped then explicitly go to the last one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but I cannot find any information on "wrapping" or "explicity" going to a view controller. Is it possible to please elaborate and provide a reference for me to look at or some example code? Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: By "wrapping" I mean when you intend to go from page 1 to page 3. You detect that you are at 1, and that you now need to go to the last page. Instead of letting the modulo formula do the work, as with the case when you go forward, you have to deal with this case explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Almo, I have figured it out and rewritten the code for `viewControllerBeforeViewController`.

First I set the currentIndex, then I check it the page displayed is the first one.

If it is then I set the current page to the last page and return it,

If else than I run my old method for going backwards, then return it as usual.

```
-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
     viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
   NSUInteger currentIndex = [myViewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

    if (currentIndex == 0) {
        currentIndex = 2;
    }else{
        --currentIndex;
        currentIndex = currentIndex % (myViewControllers.count);
    }

    return [myViewControllers objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
}
```

Comment: Looking at this, your code is redundant. You don't need the % operation anymore, since the `if(currentIndex==0)` part takes care of it. Personally, I'd do `currentIndex--; if(currentIndex == -1) currentIndex = myViewControllers.count - 1;`